# How is アェ pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation, katakana

A video game I've been playing has the following word in it:

> アェウクス

I'm not familiar with `アェ`.  Does it represent a specific sound?  If so, what sound?

If it makes sense to do so, please include `アィ`・`アゥ`・ `アォ` in your answer.

Comment: This is just a guess: In many European languages, the sound between a & e gives the "a" in "fat." Many languages don't have that sound, but it's considered somewhere between "a" (as in father) and "e" (as in pet). The Japanese ア is more like the "a" in "father," so if you wanted to specify the "a" in "fat," アェ seems reasonable.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

“アェ” is not a valid spelling of any sound in the standard usage of kana letters.  If it is used to describe any sound (in a nonstandard way), I agree with AHelps that it probably describes “æ” sound.

However, according to web search, アェウクス is a password which appears in a video game “[時空の覇者 Sa・Ga3](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%99%82%E7%A9%BA%E3%81%AE%E8%A6%87%E8%80%85_Sa%E3%83%BBGa3).”  As it is a video game, the password used in it does not have to be actually pronounceable.  It is スクウェア (the name of the company who made the game) spelled backward.

Comment: Ooh, I should have realized it was スクウェア backwards.  Thank you!

Comment: The company is now known as スクウェア・エニックス.

Comment: Like ドロップス is written スプッロド on the can in that famous Ghibli movie Grave of the Fireflies. http://blogs.c.yimg.jp/res/blog-15-a2/uran_poron/folder/572274/98/15359698/img_0?1186572558
When Japanese is written traditionally, it's top to bottom and left to right. I imagine this is like a single column version of that.

Answer (score -1):

I usually would do this in a comment, but I lack the reputation to do so.

http://translate.google.de/?q=%E3%82%A2%E3%82%A7%E3%82%A6%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9&sugexp=chrome,mod%3D10&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&sa=N&tab=wT

Click the "speaker" icon, usually Google gets those things quite right. Also I assume that you would rather spell the 'a' in 'fat' with a エ

Comment: As I wrote, “アェ” cannot appear in any word according to the Japanese orthography, and therefore there is no correct pronunciation of it.  Google Translate just treats it as アエ because アェ is not a valid spelling.